# "crashes" while exporting from VM

Tags: crash, virtualbox, redhawksdr

I am using CENTOS6 and REDHAWK2.0 (RH2.0). VM installed based on "VirtualBox 5.0.16 for Windows host" and "VirtualBox 5.0.17 r106140 Guest Additions installer image". The OS for the computer is Windows professional 7. However, whenever I export the machine profile (CENTOS6, RH2.0) from VM, all the projects listed in the REDHAWK "project explorer" window disappear (no projects show up in "project explorer" window if I reopen the REDHAWK IDE). I have tried this in different PCs, and it keeps happening. However, if I don't export the appliance, everything is OK, which means that project list in the "project explorer" window stay no matter how many times I close and open the REDHAWK IDE in the VM.

Another note:
When I close the VM, I get the following message:

---

Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library

Runtime Error!
program: C:Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxSVC.exe

R6025

### -pure virtual function call

Then, after I close this dialogue box, I got another message:

---

VirtualBox Interface has stopped working
Details:
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   VBoxSVC.exe
Application Version:    5.0.16.5871
Application Timestamp:  56d9b7f1
Fault Module Name:  MSVCR100.dll
Fault Module Version:   10.0.40219.1
Fault Module Timestamp: 4d5f034a
Exception Code: 40000015
Exception Offset:   00000000000761c9
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   3b88
Additional Information 2:   3b88e6353d8105cc00c90d3a5da0074b
Additional Information 3:   5abc
Additional Information 4:   5abc42e81271271eab3d346a48f0ce0a

Read our privacy statement online:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid= ... cid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Any clues on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen any bugs that are related between VirtualBox itself on the host and the Redhawk project explorer in the guest, but the following are steps you can take to debug further. Because your order of operations isn't clear:

1. Do not export a VM while the VM is still running. Shut it down first, then export.
2. If you were already doing that, or still have issues, ensure there are no compatibility issues between your version of host OS (Windows 7 Professional) and the version of VirtualBox (VirtualBox 5.0.16). A quick search on your error turned up [VirtualBox COM service crash at exit](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13391). Try re-installing the VirtualBox client and updating your Windows host - if there is something wrong/corrupted with VirtualBox itself then there's no telling what problems you'll have with a guest OS.
3. If you re-install VirtualBox and then re-import or add your existing VM and you still have issues inside the VM with Redhawk IDE project explorer view, you may have a corrupted IDE. Delete the eclipse folder with the IDE and re-download it.